# How to properly start a session using cookies, store it and access it in a Sinatra app using Rack sessions

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra app running on Heroku. I've had a really tough time properly setting up the cookies for my users. I've been looking at examples and documentation for a couple days now and just can't seem to crack the problem. I would like to have my users login with a email and password. If the login is successful, I want to create a cookie which expires after some set amount of time. I want the user to remain logged in if they close and re-open their browser or if I push new code to Heroku. I think that is just normal use of cookies, so if someone can help me get it going, I'd be very grateful.

Here is how I *think* I'm supposed to setup the post '/login' route.

```
post '/login/?' do

  #do_login is a helper method which checks if the user's credentials are correct

  if do_login
    use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                               :domain => 'www.Feistie.com',
                               :path => '/',
                               :expire_after => 2592000,
                               :secret => 'a_30_character_key',
                               :user_id => params[:user_id]
  end

end
```

Even if that is correct, I don't really understand it. What is the :key? I'm assuming :domain should just be set to my website as I did. What about :path? Why is :path set to '/'? Is there a place I actually set the secret key for my Rack app? I'm not totally clear on how cookie security works. I'm also not sure if I can add :user_id to the hash the way I did.

Then next part is setting up a helper "logged_in?" to see if someone is logged in?

```
def logged_in?
  !session.nil?
end
```

That is probably wrong, but I figured I'd try.

I also need to be able to check who the current user actually is. I used to do this by `session[:user_id] == @user.id` or something similar. The main question I have is how do I access the :user_id value in the cookie?

Finally the logout.

```
post '/logout/?' do
  session.clear
end
```

If you guys could get me on track with all this, it would be amazing! Thanks in advance and if you need more info, I will be glad to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much simpler than that.
http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions

```
enable :sessions

post '/login/?' do
  if do_login
    session[:user_id] = params[:user_id]
  end
end

post '/logout/?' do
  session[:user_id] = nil
end
```

I generally try to keep session management to the business logic in `get`, `post`, `before`, etc blocks. You can use a `before` filter to "log-in" the current session's user.

```
before '*' do
  set :user_id, session[:user_id]
end
```

This is completely optional, but you can put any cookie config in your rackup file:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, 
    :key => 'rack.session',
    :path => '/',
    :expire_after => 14400, # In seconds
    :secret => 'change_me'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just try setting it with `response`

```
response.set_cookie "user_id", {:value => params['user_id'], 
                                :expires => (Time.now + 52*7*24*60*60)}
```

And you can read it back any time before it expires with

```
request.cookies["user_id"]
```

To delete the cookie

```
response.delete_cookie "user_id"
```

...

Comment: Just a thought. It might be worth giving each user a random token (`SecureRandom.hex` maybe), instead of their user_id.

Comment: making a little progress. thanks. First, it should be request.cookies. Maybe I can just edit that, i see an edit button. So type this: response.delete_cookie 'user_id'
    response.set_cookie "user_id", {:value => "some data", :expires => (Time.now + 52*7*24*60*60)}
    puts request.cookies['user_id'] and the response is just "some data." I can't seem to get the entire hash as the response. Any ideas? Thanks!